# Upholstery Repair

Tags: repair, jetta, interior

The seams are starting to fail on the front seats of my '05 Jetta wagon - it looks like the leather may be failing in places as well - so I'm starting to research repair options.

I'm wondering:

- How tricky/dangerous is it to remove and recover the seats?
- How do you identify aftermarket seat covers that are safe to use with airbags?
- Would I be able to swap in a set of used seats?

Anything else I should be thinking about?

Comment: Point 1 : be very careful with airbags - usually the first operation is to disconnect them... Aftermarket seat covers - check what the manufacturer has stated. Swapping in - definitely possible - match the trim and see point 1.

Comment: @SolarMike - The first step with airbags is to *de-energize* them, even before you disconnect them. Residual energy in the system can set them off ... I agree with your premise, though ... don't play with them if you can help it!